# ¿Cuál es la forma de recorrer un bucle e imprimir Image en React Native?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

Tengo declarado este array y quiero recorrerlo en el return para que se imprima con la etiqueta Image.

```
 const appDataImages = [
{id: 1, link: '../../assets/images/face-1.png'},
{id: 2, link: '../../assets/images/face-2.png'},
{id: 3, link: '../../assets/images/face-3.png'},
{id: 4, link: '../../assets/images/face-4.png'},
{id: 5, link: '../../assets/images/face-5.png'},
{id: 6, link: '../../assets/images/face-5.png'},];
```

El problema es que cuando estoy recorriendo el bucle me sale que esta forma no es correcta y lo probé de varias maneras. El error me lo da en el require.

```
 <View style={styles.view}>
    {appDataImages.map(image => (
      <Image
        key={image.id}
        source={require(image.link)}
        style={styles.image}
      />
    ))}
  </View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo conseguí solucionar simplemente cambie el array y puse directamente el require ahí.

```
const appDataImages = [
    {id: 1, link: require('../../assets/images/face-1.png')},
    {id: 2, link: require('../../assets/images/face-1.png')},
    {id: 3, link:require('../../assets/images/face-1.png')},
    {id: 4, link: require('../../assets/images/face-1.png')},
    {id: 5, link: require('../../assets/images/face-1.png')},
    {id: 6, link: require('../../assets/images/face-1.png')},
];
```